# Hey I can't figure out how to use ::after in this case. CSS

Tags: css

I used that to describe an active element:

```
 .elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {}
```

but I also want to write something after the element, therefore I tried this:

```
 .elementor-tab-title.elementor-active:after {}
```

but that didn't work. Please help me.

**The whole code:**

.elementor-tab-title { background-color: #394e72; margin-bottom: 20px; } .elementor-tab-title.elementor-active { background-color: #182d50; box-shadow : 2px 2px 6px 1px #181818; }

**Here is what I imagine in my head:**

[1-Month-Subscription]

*text when "1-Month-Subscription" is selected

[2-Month-Subscription]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you share your codes?

Comment: As your title says, you should use `::after` and not `:after`. Also, give a more complete example: what did you put between the {} in your `::after` definition? What was the output, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Where did you put the 'something' that you wanted to write after the element? The very simplest of after settings -  .elementor-tab-title.elementor-active::after { content: 'I am the stuff written after the tab title'; } - should work. Did you have other formatting in there?

Comment: .elementor-tab-title {
    background-color: #394e72;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
 

}
.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active {
    background-color: #182d50;
      box-shadow : 2px 2px 6px 1px #181818;
}
.elementor-tab-title.elementor-active::after { content: "I am the stuff written after the tab title"; } 

That's the whole code, I also tried to add the code you recommended but it didn't work for me. I am working with the add-on Elementor for Wordpress.
Here is what I imagine in my head:

[1-Month-Subscription]
*text when "1-Month-Subscription" is selected
[2-Month-Subscription]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly edit your Question to include clarifications. Do not add those in comments.